# Собрать deb пакет

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, deb

У меня есть проект на Python. Хочу из него сделать deb пакет, чтобы устанавливать на другие компы.
Создал файл setup.py и папку debian со следующими файлами: changelog,compat,control,copyright,rules.

Запускаю команду

```
dpkg-buildpackage -b
```

Выдает ошибку

```
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package hsi
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 1.0
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution UNRELEASED
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by argus <argus@argus>
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
dpkg-source --before-build .
fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean --with python3 --buildsystem=pybuild
Use of uninitialized value $v in substitution (s///) at  /usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm line 1729, <$fd> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $v in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm line 1730, <$fd> line 7.
 dh_auto_clean -O--buildsystem=pybuild
Use of uninitialized value $v in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm line 1729, <$fd> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $v in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Dh_Lib.pm line 1730, <$fd> line 7.
E: Please add appropriate interpreter package to Build-Depends,  see pybuild(1) for details.this: $VAR1 = bless( {
             'pyvers' => '',
             'pypydef' => '',
             'parallel' => '4',
             'cwd' => '/home/argus/pack',
             'builddir' => undef,
             'sourcedir' => '.',
             'pydef' => '',
             'py3vers' => '3.9',
             'py3def' => '3.9'
           }, 'Debian::Debhelper::Buildsystem::pybuild' );
deps: $VAR1 = [];
make: *** [debian/rules:4: clean] Error 25
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean subprocess     returned exit status 2
```

Содержимое файла rules

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@ --with python3 --buildsystem=pybuild
```

Содержимое файла control

```
Source: hsi
Maintainer: Developer
Build-Depends: debhelper (>=10)

Package: hsi
Architecture: all
```

Не могу понять,где ошибка?

Comment: shebang (`#!`) в `rules` то правильно то пропиши...

Comment: Спасибо! Отредактировал вопрос, т.к. до сих пор происходит ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался
В файле control изменил строчку

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>=10),dh-python, python3-all
```

И установил python3-all